# response.data sent from php backend is empty

Tags: php, angularjs, json, email, imap

I'm working in a website of temporary emails, one of the functionality that I have to implement is getting the origin of the email(getting email's headers), so I implemented this code to do that:

backend(php):

```
function get_original_email($mailid, $address) {
global $mailbox;

if (_load_one_email($mailid, $address) !== null) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $headers = imap_fetchheader($mailbox->getImapStream(), $mailid, FT_UID);
    //$body = imap_body($mailbox->getImapStream(), $mailid, FT_UID);
    print (json_encode(array('originalEmail' => $headers)));
} else {
    error(404, 'retrieving error: invalid username/mailid combination');
}
```

}

angularjs controller:

```
self.getOriginal = function (mail, domain) {

    var firstTo = Object.keys(mail.to)[0];
    $http.get(backend_url, {params:{username: firstTo, original_email_id: mail.id, domain:domain}})
        .then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                self.originalEmail = response.data.originalEmail;
                $log.error(response); //To show response content.
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                $log.error(response, this);
                self.error = {
                    title: "HTTP_ERROR",
                    desc: "There is a problem with geting the original email. (HTTP_ERROR).",
                    detail: response
                };
            });
}
```

this code works fine the most of the emails but when I try to Signup for Blockchain.com for example, getting original fails and I get this in chrome inspector:

```
{data: "", status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}config: {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", paramSerializer: ƒ, …}data: ""headers: ƒ (d)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

I downloded the content of the headers:

```
 Return-path: <bounces+1772275-ae77-jeff=mailinbox.co@sendgrid.net>
Envelope-to: jeff@mailinbox.co
Delivery-date: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 18:25:32 +0200
Received: from o1.mail.blockchain.info ([198.21.6.174])
    by  with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128)
    (Exim 4.89)
    (envelope-from <bounces+1772275-ae77-jeff=mailinbox.co@sendgrid.net>)
    id 1dwWCK-0008U5-Eu
    for jeff@mailinbox.co; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 18:25:32 +0200
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
    d=blockchain.info; 
    h=content-transfer-encoding:content-type:from:mime-version:subject:to; 
    s=m1; bh=A+wGBBGT0nPZi611WDiY8hyoJiA=; b=BvDSkuUQpbkbwvS176xTK19
    evW+h0n9QLlMlqNQRy8pEZXRaMtPm3o9szysUlrzFB8+ucaSyCQqhdjobKRA5LvP
    L5BS9814iqFpV+Kzrb8gMc3aSl/aycBTqBxQYeuTtsWWT1I6VMHLPquVqOuS4ZjG
    n1ia1O5mFsFtvNJpligI=
Received: by filter0934p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter0934p1mdw1-27911-59C92DF5-1D
        2017-09-25 16:25:25.327461844 +0000 UTC
Received: from MTc3MjI3NQ (236.212.190.35.bc.googleusercontent.com [35.190.212.236])
    by ismtpd0001p1lon1.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id 8U6IPbOfSEO07nzJUAkd1Q
    for <jeff@mailinbox.co>; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 16:25:25.209 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 16:25:25 +0000 (UTC)
From: "Blockchain" <no-reply@blockchain.info>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Subject: Welcome To My Wallet
To: jeff@mailinbox.co
Message-ID: <8U6IPbOfSEO07nzJUAkd1Q@ismtpd0001p1lon1.sendgrid.net>
X-SG-EID: rp6B7bPLkmILpCROEdQ6zxTTWV8/jMJblylXDv403K5XiCqxnco7VnA/3IqSz7BIqYEji4cv4ijjl3
 obxT0otJleksoYG645Y4eGShknp4SWqOkaFs63Ycjvax2oooiiWDaX5/JGhenxjRDma8xla9eBS4Fg
 kwS3NpJQZSN3iSig19KAiQSGMIT4FhORo8kD0hDQAJhfzUT/JT1pcnAx8mMsZ9/JyELfQe9pet+yLB
 8=
X-Spam-Score: 10
X-Spam-Bar: +
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "", has
 identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original message
 has been attached to this so you can view it (if it isn't spam) or label
 similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
 the administrator of that system for details.

 Content preview:  Verify Your Email Thank you for creating a Blockchain wallet.
    Verify your email below to complete your setup. Yes, This Is My Email Your
    Wallet ID: 8a622806-96bd-44f3-a267-77f5af68a3dd Use your unique Wallet ID
    to log into your Blockchain wallet. Copyright © 2017 Blockchain Luxembourg
    S.A. All rights reserved. Click here to Unsubscribe [...] 

 Content analysis details:   (1.0 points, 5.0 required)

  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                             See
                             http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                              for more information.
                             [URIs: blockchain.info]
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                             domain
  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
X-redirected: yes
```

because I'm getting the content in the download function which uses the print directly without using json_encode (to send a json format ), so I believe that the problem is with the json format, but I don't what is the problem exactly, so if you have any idea thanks for sharing.

Comment: eMail was detected as a spam as per error message. Please check this link - https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block

Comment: Do you mean that the request is blocklisted, and I can't retrieve the origin??

Comment: I think there is a limit for number of eMails and it is consumed all but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks about the response, but I can send other emails and receive them normally except some websites like Blockchain.com, and for downloading there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with some special characters that may appear in the message content(the `$headers`), so I have to clean them, for that I created this function:

```
function _clean_origin($origin){
  $origin = preg_replace('/[^\da-z \n\rA-Z.,!<>()+-?]/'," ",$origin);
  return $origin;
```

}

which I call in the `get_original_email` to clean `$headers`, so I can get the headers normally.